# how to Migrate SharePoint Online page between Site collection with likes and comments?

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-migration, comments, like

We have 2 modern communication sites. We want to move our 1st site collection site pages to the second site collection with likes and comments. I have tried 3rd part trial of Sharegate and SharePoint Modern and classic copy to functionality. But none of them supports the like and comments migration.

Is it even Possible? If yes, Can anyone provide any guidance here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you can only migrate pages. Without comments and likes.

Comments and likes will be a challenge. Because these are added via a separate end points. None of the migration tools use these endpoints yet. Also, we can only add comments and likes as currently logged in user. Impersonating different users will be a challenge.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to migrate SharePoint Online pages between site collections with likes and comments, only the content on the page can be migrated.